# Guzzle How do you test Pool in side of actual applications

Tags: unit-testing, guzzle

Looking at the Guzzle tests on how they tested pool doesn't help me because they test pool its self. And I don't want to test pool per say I want to test that the way I am using it actually works.

Consider the following:

```
public function getItemHistoryForRegion(array $items, array $regions) {

    $acceptedResponses = [];

    $this->createRequests($items, $regions);

    $pool = new Pool($this->client, $this->createdRequests, [
        'concurrency' => 18,
        'fulfilled'   => function ($response, $index) use (&$acceptedResponses) {

            $responseJson = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());
            $acceptedResponses[$index] = $responseJson;

            $this->populateHistoricalDataContainer($responseJson, $acceptedResponses);
        },
        'rejected'    => function ($reason, $index) use(&$rejectedResponses)  {
            $this->eveLogHandler->messageLog($reason, 'eve_online_region_item_history_rejected_responses.log');
        },
    ]);

    $promise = $pool->promise();
    $promise->wait();

    return end($this->historicalData);
}
```

We have a series of requests that are created based on the items and regions. We then have a pool object that is created and turned into a promise which we wait on.

in side the fulfilled portion of the pool we populate a container with some
information that come back from the response.

I feel like I can remove the `$this->createRequests($items, $regions);` and the method call inside the `fulfilled` section as well as the end return statement and put that in its own method.

This then allows me to test all the functionality out side of this method.

But that still leaves me with the Pool. How do I the method? Do I? I mean once I remove everything then I am left with this:

```
public function getItemHistoryForRegion() {

    $acceptedResponses = [];

    $pool = new Pool($this->client, $this->createdRequests, [
        'concurrency' => 18,
        'fulfilled'   => function ($response, $index) use (&$acceptedResponses) {
            $responseJson = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());
            $acceptedResponses[$index] = $responseJson;
        },
        'rejected'    => function ($reason, $index) use(&$rejectedResponses)  {
            $this->eveLogHandler->messageLog($reason, 'eve_online_region_item_history_rejected_responses.log');
        },
    ]);

    $promise = $pool->promise();
    $promise->wait();

    return $acceptedResponses
}
```

Which is much better and cleaner. But how do I test the method? I don't even know where to begin. Does any one use Pool in there code bases for those who use guzzel? If so how do you test this?

The only thing I an think to do is mock the method but then once I mock it Im not really testing it ...

I could Create a method wrapper for the function and then call that function and mock this function and do a "I expect this function to be called once and to return me an array of x" But that just tests that the function name is spelled properly and that it was called. not that it fetched data and actually returns me something.

The other issue I don't want it to actually hit any api services I just want to make sure that when it runs I get an array of accepted response. Should I do the method wrapper and mocking concept? Is that even "best practices"??

**Im at a loss here. Help?**

Answer (score 0):

Your first code snippet is not as easy to test as what it could be.

It sounds like you might want to checkout [phpspec](http://www.phpspec.net/en/latest/).  I'm still new at working and developing my specs but based on the code you have listed above I might want to generate the following the following methods (to start).

Also [Guzzle MockHandler](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/testing.html#mock-handler) is / should be used when performing unit and functional testing.

```
class MyClassSpec {
    public function let() {
        // change this method call to suit the constructor of the class under test.
        $this->shouldBeConstructedWith(new Client(['handler'=> new GuzzleHttp\Handler\MockHandler($arrayOfExpectedPsr7ResultObjects)]));

        $items = ['item 1', 'item 2'];
        $regions = ['region1', 'region2'];
    }

    public function it_will_tabulate_historical_data($items, $regions) {

        $this->getItemHistoryForRegion($items, $regions);

        $this->historicalData->shouldBe($ExpectedPostCondition);
    }

    public function it_calculates_requests($items, $regions) {
        // if method returns an array;
        $this->createRequests($items, $regions)->shouldBeLike($arrayOfRequestObjects);

        // if method directly manipulates a class property
        $this->createdRequests->shouldBe($preConditionValue);
        $this->createRequests($items, $regions);
        $this->createdRequests->shouldBe($ExpectedPostConditionValue);
    }
}
```